# Optimised EmEditor Macro to Element Sort, Split, and Dedupe a single Column and Extract Count

Tags: javascript, performance, emeditor

I currently have a separated file in this format (3 columns tab "\t" separated), and “;” separates all the elements within the columns).

```
    COL1\tCOL2\tCOL3
    abc\t123;1q\tapple\t
    dfg\t234;2w\tapple;apple\t
    hij\t345;3e\tbanana;apple;cherry;\t
    klm\t456;4r\tapple;banana;cherry;banana;cherry;\t
    nop\t567;5t\t;;apple;banana;cherry;banana;;cherry;;\t
```

I would like any thoughts on an optimized macro (ideally javascript) to manipulate the file to OUTPUT this:
Column 3 is now sorted (any extra/unrequired delimiters are removed as well)and duplicates removed. New column 4 is the deduplicated element count.

```
    abc\t123;1q\tapple\t1
    dfg\t234;2w\tapple\t1
    hij\t345;3e\tapple;banana;cherry\t3
    klm\t456;4r\tapple;banana;cherry\t3
    nop\t567;5t\tapple;banana;cherry\t3
```

I have been trying similar to the below, but this method could be quicker I think.

```
    for( iRow = 2; iRow <= totalLines; iRow++ ) { //traverse eash row, start at 2nd row
      str = document.GetCell(iRow, 2, eeCellIncludeQuotes);
      var count = (str.match(/;/g) || []).length;
      var numOfElements = count + 1;
      document.SetCell( iRow, 3, numOfElements, eeAutoQuote );
    }
```

So the user should select the column they want to run this on (Column 3 in this example) and the macro would run on that column only, and output the count to a new column to the right.

The real source files will be millions of lines, so if this could be EmEditor optimized in any way, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized your macro by creating a function to count semicolons in a string rather than using a regular expression (Second version), and also used `GetColumn` and `SetColumn` methods to increase the speed (Third version). The third version will insert a column rather than overwrite the existing column.

1. **Original macro** (modified for correctness and timing)

   ```
   var start = new Date().getTime();

   var totalLines = document.GetLines();
   for( iRow = 2; iRow <= totalLines; iRow++ ) { //traverse eash row, start at 2nd row
       str = document.GetCell(iRow, 3, eeCellIncludeQuotes);
       var count = (str.match(/;/g) || []).length;
       var numOfElements = count + 1;
       document.SetCell( iRow, 4, numOfElements, eeAutoQuote );
   }

   var end = new Date().getTime();
   var time = end - start;
   alert( "Execution time: " + time + " ms" );
   ```
2. **Second version**

   ```
   function CountSemiColon( str )
   {
       var count = 0;
       for( var index = -1; ; ) {
           index = str.indexOf( ';', index + 1 );
           if( index == -1 ) {
               break;
           }
           ++count;
       }
       return count;
   }

   var start = new Date().getTime();

   var totalLines = document.GetLines();
   for( iRow = 2; iRow <= totalLines; iRow++ ) { //traverse eash row, start at 2nd row
       var str = document.GetCell(iRow, 3, eeCellIncludeQuotes);
       document.SetCell( iRow, 4, CountSemiColon( str ) + 1, eeAutoQuote );
   }

   var end = new Date().getTime();
   var time = end - start;
   alert( "Execution time: " + time + " ms" );
   ```
3. **Third version**

   ```
   function CountSemiColon( str )
   {
       var count = 0;
       for( var index = -1; ; ) {
           index = str.indexOf( ';', index + 1 );
           if( index == -1 ) {
               break;
           }
           ++count;
       }
       return count;
   }

   var start = new Date().getTime();

   var totalLines = document.GetLines();
   s1 = document.GetColumn( 3, "\n", eeCellIncludeQuotesAndDelimiter, 2, totalLines - 1 );
   sLines = s1.split( "\n" );
   s2 = "";
   nTotal = sLines.length;
   for( y = 0; y < nTotal; y++ ) {
       s2 += CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n";
   }
   x = s2.length;
   if( x > 0 ) s2 = s2.substr( 0, x - 1 );
   document.InsertColumn( 4, s2, "\n", eeDontQuote, 2 );

   var end = new Date().getTime();
   var time = end - start;
   alert( "Execution time: " + time + " ms" );
   ```
4. **Fourth version** (returns 0 for empty cell)

   ```
   function CountElements( str )
   {
       if( str.length == 0 || str == '\t' ) {   // if empty string or delimiter only, return 0
           return 0;
       }
       var count = 0;
       for( var index = -1; ; ) {
           index = str.indexOf( ';', index + 1 );
           if( index == -1 ) {
               break;
           }
           ++count;
       }
       return count + 1;   // add 1 to the Count
   }

   var start = new Date().getTime();

   var totalLines = document.GetLines();
   s1 = document.GetColumn( 3, "\n", eeCellIncludeQuotesAndDelimiter, 2, totalLines - 1 );
   sLines = s1.split( "\n" );
   s2 = "";
   nTotal = sLines.length;
   for( y = 0; y < nTotal; y++ ) {
       s2 += CountElements( sLines[y] ) + "\n";
   }
   x = s2.length;
   if( x > 0 ) s2 = s2.substr( 0, x - 1 );
   document.InsertColumn( 4, s2, "\n", eeDontQuote, 2 );

   var end = new Date().getTime();
   var time = end - start;
   alert( "Execution time: " + time + " ms" );
   ```

**Test results:**

1. 10429 ms
2. 8496 ms
3. 1803 ms
4. 1890 ms

*1 million line, 52 MB CSV file.*

If this is not fast enough, or "Out of Memory" error occurs, I will think about other methods or optimize even further, so please let me know.

Comment: Third version is MUCH faster. As per the original query, to deduplicate/sort is there a quicker way than adding the following 3 lines after the "var start..."?        
    
        document.SplitColumn("3",";",eeSplitIntoColumns,"A+",eeRemoveDuplicates | eeSortIgnorePrefix | eeSortStable,0);
        document.selection.Replace("\\t",";",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,eeExFindBOL | eeExFindEOL);
        document.selection.Replace("^;|;+$","",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,eeExFindBOL | eeExFindEOL);

Comment: I can't think of a faster way to sort/deduplicate elements in a cell. I think I will have to add a new method to macros on the next major version to do just that.

Comment: Thanks @Yutaka. Just a slight issue (I'm using the 3rd method). If the Column we are counting has no data - e.g.

        `abc\t123;1q\t\t`

The macro stil returns a count of 1, when it should be 0. Could you tweak the code?

Comment: Then you can replace s2 += CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n"; with s2 +=str.length == 0 ? "0\n" : (CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n");

Comment: As for your question regarding a faster way to sort/deduplicate elements in a column, please post a separate question for just that, and then I will answer to your new question. Let's focus one question at a time. Thank you!

Comment: Will do - I guess for the handling "0" fix part:


`s2 +=str.length == 0 ? "0\n" : (CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n");`
should be 
`s2 +=s2.length == 0 ? "0\n" : (CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n");`

Comment: It should be `s2 += sLines[y].length == 0 ? "0\n" : (CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n");`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it works fine if it's the last column, however `s2 += sLines[y].length == 0 ? "0\n" : (CountSemiColon( sLines[y] ) + 1 + "\n");` still produces "1" rather than "0" if there are any other column to the right of Col3? 


Is it possible to tweak so it runs correcly even if there are more columns to the right e.g. `COL1\tCOL2\tCOL3\tCOL4
abc\t123;1q\t\trandomtext` still produces count of 1 for Col3, but should be 0

Comment: I added the fourth version to correct it, and also optimized it for speed. I confirmed it works even if there is another column to the right of Col3. I edited my answer.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks Yutaka. Version 4 works exactly as expected and is much quicker than my v1.